# set-userphoto using ews managed api 2.2

Tags: exchangewebservices

is it possible to set the user photo using the ews api 2.2? -- not a contact photo!

same as powershell command Set-UserPhoto

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.xxx.xxx/ews/Exchange.asmx");
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this isn't possible because there is no underlying EWS operation to allow you to Set the user photo . There is a full list of the EWS operations on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb409286(v=exchg.150).aspx.

One thing you can do with EWS that would be unsupported is modify the User photo object that gets created in the Root of the Mailbox. eg if you look at the Mailbox with a Mapi editor like MFCMapi and look at Items in the NonIPM Root of the Mailbox you'll see the UserPhoto object (it has a MessageClass of IPM.UserPhoto) if a userphoto has been set. In the object there are extended properties that have the Photo stored in all the different Image formats that are supported. But I don't think this method would give you a proper solution.

Cheers
Glen